# Dotnet core Entity Framework SQL data first

Tags: sql-server, .net-core

Carefully following Microsoft tutorial instructions (from a couple dotnet core examples). Problem: I get to the `Add-Migration` step and it works perfectly - except that in SQL Server, no database shows up.

So I tried pre-creating an empty database; no tables show up. Changed from trusted connection to user id and password. Still no luck.

I have Visual Studio 2017 v15.5.7

Steps: new project: Web Core application; this time took WebAPI option.

Nuget:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (2.0.1)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (2.0.1)
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design (2.02)

Models.cs contains:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HunterDataCore.Models
{
    public class HunterContext : DbContext
    {
        public HunterContext(DbContextOptions<HunterContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Behavior> Behaviors { get; set; }
    }

    public class Behavior
    {
        [Key]
        public string BehaviorId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectKey { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs .. only changed one function:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    var connection = @"Server=Puppy;Database=HunterDataCore;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
    services.AddDbContext<HunterContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
}
```

Then it says using Package Manage Console:

```
add-migration InitialCreate
```

It indeed adds a `Migrations` folder along with Initial Create: Up/Down/BuildTargetModel functions.

The UP function:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Behaviors",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    BehaviorId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 500, nullable: true),
                    ProjectKey = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 200, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Behaviors", x => x.BehaviorId);
                });
}
```

No runs, no hits, no errors, no one left on base -- and NO database or if I pre-add it, the database does NOT contain any new tables.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx), which is the one I suppose you are using:

> Code First Migrations has two primary commands that you are going to
>   become familiar with.
>
> - Add-Migration will scaffold the next migration based on changes you    have made to your model since the last migration was created
> - Update-Database will apply any pending migrations to the database

I interpret it as that the Add-Migration would create the files in the project representing the migration to be applied, while the Update-Database will apply such migrations, so you need to execute such Update-Database to actually create/update the database.

Plus, you can use the -verbose modifier to both to see if there is some unexpected stuff happening.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I Stopped Reading after the add-migrations thinking that I should have seen the results.  MY BAD.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the database from command line. It doesn't automatically apply the migrations when run.

`dotnet ef database update`

It uses the database configuration and connection that is set up in your code. I.e. it sort-of actually runs your app to achieve this.